# The commands openany and oneside in the book document class

Tags: header-footer, books, preamble

I have the following code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1.25in,bottom=1.25in,headsep=30pt,heightrounded] 
   {geometry}
 \usepackage[x11names, svgnames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{amsthm}
 %==============================================================
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \fancyhf{}
 \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
 \fancyhead[LO]{\small\nouppercase{\rightorleftmark}}
 \fancyhead[RE]{\small\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
 \renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\thechapter\hspace{0.25cm} #1}{}}
 \renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{\markright{\thesection\hspace{0.4cm}#1}{}}
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

 \makeatletter
 \newcommand{\rightorleftmark}{%
 \begingroup\protected@edef\x{\rightmark}%
 \ifx\x\@empty
  \endgroup\leftmark
 \else
  \endgroup\rightmark
 \fi}
 \makeatother
 %===============================================================
 \usepackage{lipsum}

 \begin{document}

 \frontmatter
  \tableofcontents

 \mainmatter
  \chapter{Introduction}
   \lipsum[1-10]

  \chapter{Preliminaries}
   \section{Basics}
    \lipsum[1-15]

 \chapter{$C4$-Modules}
  \lipsum[1-30]


  \end{document}
```

Before adding `oneside` command the chapter name and page number interchange in header from one page to another in Chapter 1 & 3, and the chapter name appears in the top right of the header in Chapter 2. This is what precisely I want. After adding `oneside`, this behaviour changed. I don't know why. How can I fix this problem? Also, if I remove `oneside` command, I get a blank page immediately after the table of contents. How can I get rid of this blank page?.

I also appreciate if anyone can provide me with an enhanced form of this code.

Comment: the only thing `oneside` does is to do what you describe, instead of having two styles for left and right pages you just have one style used on all pages. Just remove that option.

Comment: Ok. I removed that option. But, as I said, I have another problem which is the blank page generated automatically after TOC. I tried `\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage` after `\tableofcontents` and this worked for me. Is the best practice ? @DavidCarlisle

Comment: no you will get odd pages on the left and even pages on the right which will confuse everybody.  If you want to reset the page numbers to 1 after the toc you really need that blank page

Comment: I don't want that blank page. What can I do?

Comment: write more text so the table of contents is longer, or don't use `\mainmatter`  You really don't want page 1 to be on a right hand page. presumably your real document would have a title page before the table of contents and then the blank page will go anyway. while the document is in draft don't worry about it.

Answer (score 4):

Clearly you do not want `oneside` as you have separate `left` and `right` styles.

Normally `openany` means that `\clearpage` is used rather than `\cleardoublepage` so that pages may open to an odd or even page.

However this applies to chapters and backmatter but not `\frontmatter` or
`\mainmatter`

This is due to a change made in 1998 and documented in the sources

```
%  \subsubsection{Front Matter, Main Matter, and Back Matter}
%
%    A book contains these three (logical) sections. The switch
%    |\@mainmatter| is true iff we are processing Main Matter.  When
%    this switch is false, the |\chapter| command does not print
%    chapter numbers.
%
%    Here we define the commands that start these sections.
%  \begin{macro}{\frontmatter}
%    This command starts Roman page numbering and turns off chapter
%    numbering.  Since this restarts the page numbering from 1, it
%    should also ensure that a recto page is used.
% \changes{v1.3r}{1996/05/26}{Make this command react to the option
%    \texttt{openany}}
% \changes{v1.3y}{1998/05/05}{Two years on: Make this command not
%    react to the option \texttt{openany} as this makes the
%    verso/recto numbering wrong: see pr/2754 for discussion}
```

The referenced report is

https://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=latex%2F2754

The issue is that (unlike `\chapter`) `\mainmatter` does not just force a new page it rests the page number to 1. You really need page 1 to be on a right hand page as otherwise the entire page heading left/right style selection is based on odd page numbers being on right hand pages and even numbers on the left.

So either accept the blank page (which will anyway go if you write more chapters and have a longer table of contents) or use `oneside` and don't use separate styles for odd and even pages.

---

The blank page is just a temporary thing and will come and go as you edit the document. In particular if you have more frontmatter such as a title, then the page will naturally fall on a right hand page without a blank page:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1.25in,bottom=1.25in,headsep=30pt,heightrounded] 
   {geometry}
 \usepackage[x11names, svgnames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{amsthm}
 %==============================================================
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
   \setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \fancyhf{}
 \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
 \fancyhead[LO]{\small\nouppercase{\rightorleftmark}}
 \fancyhead[RE]{\small\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
 \renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\thechapter\hspace{0.25cm} #1}{}}
 \renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{\markright{\thesection\hspace{0.4cm}#1}{}}
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

 \makeatletter
 \newcommand{\rightorleftmark}{%
 \begingroup\protected@edef\x{\rightmark}%
 \ifx\x\@empty
  \endgroup\leftmark
 \else
  \endgroup\rightmark
 \fi}
 \makeatother
 %===============================================================
 \usepackage{lipsum}

 \begin{document}

 \title{something}
 \author{somebody}
 
 \frontmatter

 \maketitle


  \tableofcontents

 \mainmatter
  \chapter{Introduction}
   \lipsum[1-10]

  \chapter{Preliminaries}
   \section{Basics}
    \lipsum[1-15]

 \chapter{$C4$-Modules}
  \lipsum[1-30]


  \end{document}
```